# Multiple AngularJS bar graphs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chart

I am having a REST API which gives me data like:

```
{
    "day" : "monday",
    "expense" : 120
}
```

I have created a bar graph using angular-chart and this data but what I want is that whenever Monday comes again the code should automatically create another bar graph and the same happens every time Monday comes. Any scalable way to do that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean another bar on the same graph or a whole new graph? Please try to be more detailed in your question and very concise thank you.

Comment: Another whole new graph @JoshuaJWilborn